# Object reactivity of complex object

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an issue with complex object reactivity.
I've read everything I can on stack to find a way to solve it, but nothing works. I've looked at object reactvity and array caveats on vuejs, but not working either.
So I'm asking some help please.

Let me explain the project:
I have 2 columns :
- on the left side, I CRUD my content
- on the right side, I display the results

I have my object, and I'm adding new elements on its "blocks" property (text, images, etc...)

```
[
  {
    "uid": 1573224607087,
    "animation": "animationName",
    "background": {
      "bckColor": "#ff55ee",
      ...
    },
    "blocks": []
  }
]
```

On click event, I add a new element via this method. Everything is ok, I can CRUD a block.

```
addBloc(el) {
   if (el.type == "text") {
        const datasA = {
          type: "text",
          uid: Date.now(),
          slideId: this.pagination.currentPage,
          content: el.content,
          css: {
            color: "#373737",
            ...
          },
      ...
        };
        this.slides[this.pagination.currentPage].blocks.push(datasA);
        this.$bus.$emit("newElement", datasA);
}
```

To modify the order of my elements on the display side, I added a drag and drop module to move my block on my DOM tree. [Smooth dnd](https://github.com/kutlugsahin/smooth-dnd)

The problem is, when I drang&drop my element, my object is updated correctly, but the DOM isn't. The dragged element goes back to its initial position. 
What is strange, when I try to modify my block (the one I dragged), it modifies the other one.

I'me adding a small video, so you can see what's happening.

[Small animation to show you what's going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W607f.gif)

I add some more explainations.
I use event bus to communicate between my components, and the right side is using its own object!

I don't know how I can solve this issue.
Tell me if you need more information.
Thank you all !

**EDIT 1 :** 
I added an id to each block to see what happens when I start Drag&Drop. ==> blocks are moving correctly. The problem is not coming from the method onDrop() but from my nested components if I understand well. They don't update. I'm going to search for this new issue.

[I've added a new gif to show what's going on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wmJF.gif)

This is the nested structure

TheSidebar.vue => top container

```
<Container
 :data-index="i"
 @drop="onDrop(i,$event)"
 :get-child-payload="itemIndex => getChildPayload(i, itemIndex)"
 lock-axis="y"
>
  <Draggable
   v-show="pagination.currentPage === i"
   v-for="(input, index) in slides[i].blocks"
   :key="index.uid"
   :id="'slideBlocksContainer'+index"
   class="item"
>
 blockId #{{input.uid}}
  <AppContainer
   v-if="input.type == 'text'"
   :blocType="input.type"
   :placeholder="input.content"
   :id="index"
   :slideId="i"
></AppContainer>

 </Draggable>
</Container>
```

Then I have my AppContainer.vue file, which is a top level. In this I have the specific elements of each input type
And I have AppElement.vue file, which is common elements, I can use everywhere

Something like this

TheSidebar

--AppContainer

----AppElement

Know I don't know yet, how to force vue to update AppContainer.vue and AppElement.vue

**EDIT 2 :**
As suggested [in this article](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/) I've changed the key of the component and now , when I drag and drop my elements, they stay where they are dropped. 
What I see also, is that the AppElement inputs, are related to their own AppContainer. So everything is ok now, but I don't know if it is best practices.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that the Smooth dnd library you are using is not updating the array of blocks that you are passing to it, it is likely making a copy of the array internally. So when you change the position of the blocks by dragging and dropping, you are not changing your blocks array, just the internal copy.

Looking at the Smooth dnd documentation, if you wanted to access the modified array you could try using the drag-end event handler:

```
onDragEnd (dragResult) {
  const { isSource, payload, willAcceptDrop } = dragResult
}
```